# How to have a fix gap between float:left element to stop next element to move position if current element changes size?

Tags: html, css

This is a layout for a calendar. In this calendar user can chose month by selecting the month desire, month hovered over changes size to give a feedback to users. The month that is hovered over pushes the next months to the right, this is cause because the size of the element has changed and moves everything forward a bit.

I tried fixing this problem by giving the months label a specific size, the problem with that was that month such as June will have a much bigger space gap than February since there is less letters.

How can I fix this issue keeping all the gaps bettwen each month the same without changing the positions of the next elements?

Thanks

```css
#coil_calendar_container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 8vh auto 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 850px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(grey, black);
  color: orange;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
}

#coil_calendar_container p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.top_display_layout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.top_display_layout .coil_month_selection {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
}

.coil_label_month {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  max-width: 120px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.coil_label_month:hover {
  font-weight: bolder !important;
  font-size: 28px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="coil_calendar_container">
  <div class="top_display_layout">
    <p>09<br>Monday</p>
    <div class="coil_month_selection">
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="Jan-coil" onclick="month_select(1);">January</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="Feb-coil" onclick="month_select(2);">February</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="Mar-coil" onclick="month_select(3);">March</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="Apr-coil" onclick="month_select(4);">April</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="May-coil" onclick="month_select(5);">May</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="June-coil" onclick="month_select(6);">June</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="July-coil" onclick="month_select(7);">July</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="Aug-coil" onclick="month_select(8);">August</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="Sep-coil" onclick="month_select(9);">September</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="Oct-coil" onclick="month_select(10);">October</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="Nov-coil" onclick="month_select(11);">November</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="Dec-coil" onclick="month_select(12);">December</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can ' duplicate ' your links and show the duplicated content which will have an absolute position, so it won't push the rest of the items left and right.

This can be done in a number of ways. I will show how to do it with `pseudo-elements` in CSS.

**First** you need to assign a `title` attribute to each `link` ( div in your case ) that is the same with the text displayed . For eg for div with `january` add `tittle="January"` and so on.

**Then** use the `content` attribute to fetch the element title and add it to the `:before` pseudo-element. This before has position absolute and visibility hidden.

**Then** on hover, change the visibility of the element to hidden, and the one of the before to visibile. Add all the styles  you want ( font-size, font-weight etc. ) to the `before` pseudo-element.

I used `visibility` because while it hides the element, that element still occupies space and can be 'touched' with events like hover,click,focus etc.

**HINT** : if you have a lot of links ( divs ) you can add the title automatically with javascript/jquery ( take the text and add it as $(link).attr("title", text ) )

See snippet below, let me know if this works for you.
*I added title to the first 7 items*

```css
#coil_calendar_container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 8vh auto 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 850px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(grey, black);
  color: orange;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
}

#coil_calendar_container p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.top_display_layout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.top_display_layout .coil_month_selection {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
}

.coil_label_month {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  max-width: 120px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.coil_label_month:before {
  content: " " attr(title) "";
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: bolder !important;
  font-size: 28px !important;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  visibility: hidden
}

.coil_label_month:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
}

.coil_label_month:hover {
  visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<div id="coil_calendar_container">
  <div class="top_display_layout">
    <p>09<br>Monday</p>
    <div class="coil_month_selection">
      <div class="coil_label_month" title="January" id="Jan-coil" onclick="month_select(1);">January</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="Feb-coil" onclick="month_select(2);" title="February">February</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="Mar-coil" onclick="month_select(3);" title="March">March</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="Apr-coil" onclick="month_select(4);" title="April">April</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="May-coil" onclick="month_select(5);" title="May">May</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="June-coil" onclick="month_select(6);" title="June">June</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="July-coil" onclick="month_select(7);" title="July">July</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="Aug-coil" onclick="month_select(8);">August</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="Sep-coil" onclick="month_select(9);">September</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="Oct-coil" onclick="month_select(10);">October</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="Nov-coil" onclick="month_select(11);">November</div>
      <div class="coil_label_month" id="Dec-coil" onclick="month_select(12);">December</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: whoever downvoted please leave a comment why . thanks :D

Comment: wasnt me who downvote. but thanks for the answer i appreciate the time. I will give it a go then letyou know how it goes.